# Determining closed loop stability by nyquist criterion

Tags: control-system, matlab

```
G(s)H(s)=2.2/s(s+1)(s^2+2s+2)
```

how to determine the closed loop stability using the nyquist criterion and how should I start implementing on matlab

Comment: This is an EE site and although some questions are not quite on topic, they are given some credence on the basis that some work has been demonstrated in understanding the problem. You have passed this test yet and nobody knows your skill level so making an answer seems doubly pointless.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange rohit, when posting homework questions you should try to prove that you made some effort solving it and preferably show your progress showing the point in where you are stuck, not just ask how to do this.

Comment: Rohit K...at least you should not only use abbreviations like G and H without some additional information. Of course, we could have an estimate about its meaning - however, a good answer requires a clear question without the need for interpretation.